# Angular 2 - Get the name of the current location using geolocation using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services

I am working on a project where I want to get my current location (`City Name`) using `Typescript`. I want to create a service which would do this for me. I have written the code below:

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class CurrentLocationService {

    constructor(private _http: Http) {}

    getCurrentLocation(): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.get('http://ipinfo.io/json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
        .map(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return Observable.throw(error.json());
        });
    }
}
```

But, this `Service` returns the wrong values to me. When i execute `http://ipinfo.io/json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK` on the browser URL the values i get back are:

```
  "city": "Munich",
  "region": "Bavaria",
  "country": "DE",
```

which are true in my case, but the Service above would return as value `Connaught Place, IN` which are wrong.
Is there a more precise way to get the current location using a service in `Typescript`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the callback in the url. This works for me.
Here is ipinfo documentation. [documentation](http://ipinfo.io/developers/full-ip-details)

```
getCurrentIpLocation(): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.get('http://ipinfo.io')
        .map(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return Observable.throw(error.json());
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find your current location by latitude and longitude:

```
getCurrentLocation(lat,lng): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lng+"&sensor=true")
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json());
      });
  }
```